# Access value inside params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Rails 5
```

I am trying to access one of the params

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>".......", 
  "temp_file_path"=>"{:value=>\"/home/utils/rails/fw_export/tmp/1510608598.csv\"}", 
  "button"=>""
}
```

specifically, temp_file_path. I tried:

```
temp_file_path = params[:temp_file_path][:value]
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
```

How do I access the value?

I also tried params["temp_file_path"][:value]

## Solution:

I was passing the temp_file_file path as part of the params, as follows (from a View):

```
= hidden_field_tag :temp_file_path, :value => temp_file_path
```

I changed it to:

```
 = hidden_field_tag :temp_file_path, temp_file_path
```

and  now the value is accessible as:

```
params[:temp_file_path]
```

Comment: `params[:temp_file_path]` is a `String`. If you want to access `[:value]`, then `params[:temp_file_path]` needs to be a valid `Hash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hash is not valid:

```
{
    "utf8" => "✓",
    "authenticity_token" => ".......", 
    "temp_file_path" => { "value" => "/home/utils/rails/fw_export/tmp/1510608598.csv\" }, 
    "button" => ""
 }
```

The above would be a valid hash.

You can access it as: `params["temp_file_path"]["value"]`

Also, symbolizing the keys will let you access the hash using symbols.
Seep symbolizing symbolizes nested hashes:
https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_symbolize_keys

```
params.deep_symbolize_keys
```

Now you can access it as: `params[:temp_file_path][:value]`